# Date Object not working with specific timezone

Tags: javascript

When I try to convert the date string object to format it, it's throwing me an error. It's working for all other `timezones`.

```
alert(new Date("12/12/1989 06:10 AM HST"))
```

Why is the above alert throwing me invalid date?

Comment: The date string is not in valid ISO format.

Comment: why is it working with alert(new Date("12/12/1989 06:10 AM EST"))

Comment: To answer that, you probably have to take a look at your browser's source code. Date parsing outside of the specification is a wild wild west and you really, really should avoid it.